# Export Makefile parameter

Tags: linux, environment-variables, make

How can I change exported value to one passed by parameter?

Makefile:

```
default_value=Default-Value
export ENV_VALUE=default_value

build:
      python3 script.py
```

execution:

```
$ make build
python3 script.py
ENV_VALUE: default_value
script executed.!
$ make build default_value=modified_value
python3 script.py
ENV_VALUE: default_value
script executed.!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export ENV_VALUE="$(default_value)"
```